# Progress Bar in Google Drive Upload

Tags: upload, google-drive-api, progress

Is there any way to create a progress bar for uploads to Google Drive?. I'm using the Google Drive SDK for Javascript. I can not find anything at all in their documentation.

Really appreciate it a little help.

Comment: Google Drive does not have a progress status but you can fake one according to https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#resumable  You need to send the data in chunks and use the returned `Content-Range` header for each chunk to reflect the upload status.

Comment: Hi @Anthony, How to capture that response while using php client library?

Comment: Look into this might lead you the right way. Havent found the path myself, but still looking. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/media_upload Look at this line. Got to be something to do with it here... insertRequest.ProgressChanged += Upload_ProgressChanged; insertRequest.ResponseReceived += Upload_ResponseReceived;

Answer (score 1):

I have consulted many codes, practically all I've found on Google during these weeks, but none show me the solution.

The last thing I've tried is webkitSlice, but really it seems a little crazy to implement that solution. I've tried and Google Drive I returns an error.

I find it impossible not to find any site with an upload with progress bar across the network.

The truth is that I'm going crazy with this issue. I have a website that is finished but without a progress bar can not see the light.

UF, thanks for your help.