# Upload to Google Drive and show progress percentage

Tags: javascript, php, google-drive-api

I'm using the code below to upload large files to Google Drive. How can I display the progress as a numeric percentage?

I don't want to show a progress bar, just a percentage like "20%".

**server.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('upload.html');
}

function uploadFiles(form) {

  try {

    var dropbox = "uploads";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("VideoName_Number: " + form.myName);

    return "Episode uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();

  } catch (error) {

    return error.toString();
  }

}
```

**upload.html**

```
<div>
  <form id="myForm">
      <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="VideoName_Number">
      <input type="file" name="myFile">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload Anime" 
             onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                      .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                      return false;">
  </form>

  <div id="output"></div>

  <script>
      function fileUploaded(status) {
          document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
      }
  </script>

  <style>
   input { display:block; margin: 20px; }
  </style>
</div>
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813966/progress-bar-in-google-drive-upload

Comment: Thanks , useful, ^^ , no it isn duplicate because its not multiple using chuncs its one file one upload , completely different system , But Im trying it now maybe its better &&

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#resumable is indeed the answer. You need to chunk the file yourself and bump your progress indicator after each chunk. Eg. your file is 10MB: break it into 10 x 1MB chunks, after uploading each chunk, add 10% to your progress counter.

Comment: @pinoyyid, I've already done that, but using the php client library, there is no way to get chunk status before the file is done uploading, would you please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32379007/1447772

Comment: the don't use the library. Just call rest directly. It's very easy

Answer (score 1):

There is a full article on how to use the google drive api using pure javascript only. The article use the external file (Jquery) known as MediaUploader. You can test a quick demo here.

[Demo of the google drive using javascript completely](https://bytutorial.com/tutorials/google-api/introduction-to-google-drive-api-using-javascript)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.