# Make requests and handle responses for resumable upload: Google Drive api [php]

Tags: php, file-upload, google-drive-api

I'm using the API Client Library for PHP (Beta) to work with google drive api, So far I can authorize and and upload a file in chuncks.
According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#resumable), these three steps should be taken to upload a file:

> - Start a resumable session.
> - Save the resumable session URI.
> - Upload the file.

Which I think the Client Library handles.
Again, according to the documentation, if I want to show the progress or [resume an interrupted upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#resume-upload), or to handle errors I need to capture the response and also be able to send requests like this:

```
> PUT {session_uri} HTTP/1.1 Content-Length: 0 Content-Range: bytes
> */2000000
```

But I have no idea how should I make such request and where can I get the response from, the php code I'm using to upload,like any other php code, only returns values when it is done executing, which is when the upload is done.
here is the function I'm using to upload files (Resumable):

```
function uploadFile($service,$client,$filetoUpload,$parentId){
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->title = $filetoUpload['name'];
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    
    // Set the parent folder.
      if ($parentId != null) {
        $parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
        $parent->setId($parentId);
        $file->setParents(array($parent));
      }
  
    // Call the API with the media upload, defer so it doesn't immediately return.
    $client->setDefer(true);
    $request = $service->files->insert($file);
    
    // Create a media file upload to represent our upload process.
    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
      $client,
      $request,
      $filetoUpload['type'],
      null,
      true,
      $chunkSizeBytes
    );
    $media->setFileSize(filesize($filetoUpload['tmp_name']));
    
    // Upload the various chunks. $status will be false until the process is
    // complete.
    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($filetoUpload['tmp_name'], "rb");

    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
      set_time_limit(120);    
      $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
      $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
     }
    
    // The final value of $status will be the data from the API for the object
    // that has been uploaded.
    $result = false;
    if($status != false) {
      $result = $status;
      set_time_limit(30);
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($result);
    }
    
    fclose($handle);
    // Reset to the client to execute requests immediately in the future.
    $client->setDefer(false);
}
```

Should i make a separate php file to handle these requests?
if so, How should tell that which file's status I'm requesting for?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Apperantly, the *BETA* Client API simply doesn't support resuming Uploads.
Please see [this issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/658) on Github, which asks for fixing this. Of course it should be easy to modify the class (see below) and create a Pull-request to enable support for resuming existing uploads when the session-URL is supplied.

However, there's an easy way to get the progress after an chunk has been uploaded.
The `Google_Http_MediaFileUpload`-object (`$media` in your example) has a public method called 'getProgress' which can be called anytime.
(Please have a look at the  [source code](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Http/MediaFileUpload.php#L110) of the API-client-library).

To get the upload status, I'd add a parameter to modify the progress precision by adjusting the chunk size. Since the more chunks are used, the more protocol overhead is generated, setting the precision as low as possible should be avoided.

Therefore, you could modify your source code as below to output the progress after each chunk:

```
function uploadFile($service,$client,$filetoUpload,$parentId,$progressPrecision = 1){
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->title = $filetoUpload['name'];
$filesize = filesize($filetoUpload['tmp_name']);
//minimum chunk size needs to be 256K
$chunkSizeBytes = min( $filesize / 100 * $progressPrecision, 262144);

// Set the parent folder.
  if ($parentId != null) {
    $parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
    $parent->setId($parentId);
    $file->setParents(array($parent));
  }

// Call the API with the media upload, defer so it doesn't immediately return.
$client->setDefer(true);
$request = $service->files->insert($file);

// Create a media file upload to represent our upload process.
$media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
  $client,
  $request,
  $filetoUpload['type'],
  null,
  true,
  $chunkSizeBytes
);
$media->setFileSize($filesize);
```

…

```
while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
  set_time_limit(120);    
  $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
  $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
  if(!$status){ //nextChunk() returns 'false' whenever the upload is still in progress
   echo 'sucessfully uploaded file up to byte ' . $media->getProgress() . 
   ' which is ' . ( $media->getProgress() / $chunkSizeBytes ) . '% of the whole file';
  }
 }
```

Hope this helps. I'll see if I can find some time to add resume-support to the client Library.

EDIT: according to [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques), the chunks need to be at least 256KB big. Changed in code.

EDIT2: I just added a [Pull request](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/pull/675) To add the Resume-Feature. If it gets rejected you could still decide whether it would be ok for you to modify/extend the client. If it gets accepted, just use store the return value of `$media->getResumeUri()` in a database, and later call `$media->resume($previously_stored_return_value)` after instantiation to resume the process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,I think progress should be called from a separate php or function because this only returns all status data when the script is done executing which is when the whole file is uploaded. For resumable upload, Do you think it'd better to work with node.js or javascript (+python) or it can be done with php? do those libraries support resumable upload?

Comment: I think this would generate much more headache than make it easier. The cause for the output to appear after everything was finished is output-buffering (search SO to see how to disable it). To resume the upload, it's neccesary to save some session information, the best place would be a database. The easiest way would be to serialize the whole `$media` object and unserialize it in another script to resume.

Comment: If it's not an option to disable Output-Buffering (probably in a shared hosting environment), you could still change the line `echo 'suc`... to save the progress in a database, and modify the Client-Side (assuming JavaScript) to request that status every second.

Comment: @RamtinGh: Did you have a look at the PR?

Comment: thanks, I'm travelling right now, so I'll try your solutions in a few days, bounty awarded anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: I tried using `$media->resume($resumeURI)` but nothing happens after calling that, one more thing, Documentation says that we should resume by sending the remaining bytes of the file, how do I get only remaining bytes from the client to my server?

Comment: Hi. This isn't yet supported, but i think the Pull Request will be merged soon. In the meanwhile, just download the files from the pull request (see my Link). I'll add an example for resuming later!

Comment: Wow, thanks for quick response, I've already downloaded and replaced the code in MediaFileUpload.php, for test purpose, I'm trying to use `resume` after first chunk to see if it works, but it didn't, and also please let me know if there is a way to store response status code along with progress for error handling. (like 5xx errors).

Comment: ATM I don't know how to access the status code, but the progress is fetched from google when calling `resume()`, then you can get the position (in bytes) from `getProgress()` and just call `fseek($handle, $media->getProgress()`, to continue where you paused (in fact, this also helps if you send some data but it isn't stored on googles servers)

Comment: I'm still struggling with this and couldn't make the resume work, I stop after first chunk and I call resume() but nothing happens, by the way, when uploading file with php, chunks first go to my server's temp right? so for resuming, how is it handled to only upload the remaining part? and last question, can I get upload ID/upload URI "before" starting to upload the media? i want to send it as a response to the JS so I can refer to it for later actions (like querying the progress from my DB)

Answer (score 0):

On the first instance, make an upload call and get the `resumeUri`:

```
  $chunk  = fread($handle, 1*1024*1024);
  $result = $media->nextChunk($chunk);

  $resumeUri = $media->getResumeUri();
  $offset    = ftell($handle);
```

On the second instance use the same `resumeUri` to resume the upload from where we left out by calling `resume()` function before `nextChunk()` function:

```
 if ($resumeUri) {
    $media->resume($resumeUri);
 }

 fseek($handle, $offset);       
 $chunk = fread($handle, 1*1024*1024);

 $result = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
```

Repeat the process until the `$result` variable has truthy value.

Comment: @Ramtin Gh hope this helps, in case if u still didnt find ur solution